# How do I know which firewall is installed on my Red Hat 4 system?

Tags: firewall, redhat-enterprise-linux

How do I know which firewall is installed on my Red Hat 4 system?

Are there any commands or procedures I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see all software installed look at a YUM or other RH software installers, I'm not sure what had RH 4 uses. You can also get a list of software from a command line interface (terminal) By using the command:

```
rpm -qa > install.txt
```

Then view it in a text editor.

Linux uses IPCHAINS so the firewall is built in to the IP stack. You can read up on Linux firewalling at linux.com. A useful GUI program for implementing a firewall rule set is FIRESTARTER for Gnome.

Comment: A RHEL4 system uses iptables, not ipchains. ipchains is the older firewall implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your RHEL4 system is using iptables. The rule set is stored in /etc/sysconfig/iptables. Read up on iptables, and do a few Google searches. There are plenty of examples out there.